# Products which adhere to human nail while still being removable/reusable?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am at loss as to what I can use for my project. I require a product which can adhere to the human nail (not any damaging glues) while still being easily removable. There will be a degree of 'overlay' on the nail so it's going to need to cover the entire nail plus a bit more (maybe seen with fake nails?).

I've looked online and video tutorials on adding fake nails isn't convenient (while it could work). My biggest problem is I don't want to damage the nail so I can't use any popular practices often seen in beauty salons.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Since you already took the [tour], all that remains for me is to point you towards the [help], where anything unclear about the site will be explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try flour and water paste or washable school pva glue. Start with the flour. It would be an interesting experiment to try a 50/50 mix of both.
Another possibility is rubber cement (art gum). This will be quicker drying.

Answer (score 0):

[Not a chemist] I like the glue on quality masking tape, also known as painters' tape. It seems to perform as you require, except it is adhering to wood or paint, not nail. In my experience it hardens over time and becomes difficult to remove, but for a few months in normal conditions it comes off with no trace.
I'd look at glues from double sided adhesive tapes too.
There's a kind of transparent blob glue they use in Europe to stick paper or card "extras" onto magazines. I have reused this before, but you will need to reduce the thickness to stick something to a nail elegantly.